# strange behavior of request methods while ajax request

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring

I have such method in my controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping ("/admin/users")
public class AdminUserController {
..
  @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
  public @ResponseBody boolean deleteUser(@PathVariable("id") int id,
                             HttpServletResponse response) {
     ..
  }
..
}
```

and this is ajax request

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/admin/users/'+id,
  type: 'delete',
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
  },
  error: function(e){
    console.log(e);
  }
});
```

When I send this request, it's fails and I get 405. When I looked at response header I saw this `Allow:"GET"`.

Ok. I change in ajax request 'delete' to 'get' but then I get in response `Allow:"DELETE"` ..

What it can be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that DELETE actions are not allowed by your server security configurations, and basically the header:

```
ALLOW: GET
```

is suggesting you to try a GET request instead, but since you specified

```
method = RequestMethod.DELETE
```

Spring in rejecting that GET invocation to the method.

you should change `method = RequestMethod.DELETE` to `method = RequestMethod.GET`
and issue an HTTP GET request.

Let me know if this helps.